# How to make changes in multiple shopify stores simultaneously?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have 2 shopify stores in with the same theme only one in german and the other in english. The url for the stores is e.g. [de.myshopify.com](http://de.myshopify.com) and [us.myshopify.com](http://us.myshopify.com). I need a solution so that i can have a master branch or something like that where i can make changes to the both sites. Can this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to theme changes you can start two separate terminals in the same folder but using two different environment variables or two different `config.yml` files.

Example `config.yml`:

```
us:
  password: ****
  theme_id: "****"
  store: us.myshopify.com

de:
  password: ****
  theme_id: "****"
  store: de.myshopify.com
```

And two terminals using the following arguments: `theme watch -e de` and `theme watch -e us`

This will upload the files to the two stores at the same time on save.

Or if you are lazy like me to open two terminals each time, you can create a `.bat` file that will do this for you:

`start.bat`

```
start cmd /k theme watch -e us
start cmd /k theme watch -e de
```

And what ever is the alternative for Linux/Mac users.

---

If you are referring to product content updates and such on both stores, then you will have to look for some kind of App for this, since there is no way to achieve this by default.